# How to change the image source onClick?

Tags: jquery, image, onclick, src

Alright I have a div that contains an image,

```
<div id="image">
<img src="images/medium/1.png" />
</div>
```

Now I want to change the src into images/medium/2.png when I click on a link with jQuery.

I have searched but couldn't find it that's why i'm asking here.
I am a beginner with jQuery so I would appreciate it if you explain everything very well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('a.imageChanger').click(function()
{
    $('#image img').attr('src','newImage.png');
}
```

This will probably do the trick, but I'm not sure if this is a nice way of doing it, because the texture has to be loaded again. Most of the time, you'll switch between two images that are already in your div. Set one to visible and one to hidden on the click method.

Example

```
<a href="somelink" class="imageChanger">Click here</a>

<div id="image">
    <img class="currentImage">
    <img class="hiddenImage">
</div>
```

The javascript:

```
// toggle both classes that display or hide an image.
$('a.imageChanger').click(function()
{
    $('#image img')each(function()
    {
        $(this).toggleClass('currentImage');
        $(this).toggleClass('hiddenImage');
    });
});
```

This script only works with 2 images, not with 3 or more. But there are a lot of rotator plugins already available.
And the css:

```
.hiddenImage
{
    display:none;
}

.currentImage
{

}
```

I didn't test this code, but it will look like something like this. It is just a concept.

Comment: Ooh I just noticed this answer XD I';ll try this one :)

Comment: @Roy: Well it should work actually, but I'll give you an example of how you could do it too.

Comment: @Roy: Sorry, i didn't read your question correctly. I'll edit the post right away.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("LINK SELECTOR GOES HERE").click(function(){
    $("#image img").attr("src","images/medium/2.png");
});
```

But if you really only intend to do this once, you may want to use

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: This will update the src attribute of whatever is selected by the link selector. The OP wants to update the src attribute of an unrelated image.

Comment: @druttka you're right, I had it righ tand then messed it up in an edit when I realize he wanted to click a link and not the element.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`$("#image img").attr("src", "images/medium/2.png")` should do the trick. It selects the `img` element within the element with `id` "image", then changes the `src` attribute.

You can run this in the `click` event handler of your link like so:

```
$("#linkId").click(function() {
    $("#image img").attr("src", "images/medium/2.png");
});
```

Comment: No, you can't assign to that.

Comment: How about what OP asked, how to change it on click?

Comment: So the above comment by kingjiv makes sense, what I originally had was `.attr("src") = "2.png"` - but you can't assign a value that way with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#image').click(function(){ // Or whatever element you want to click on
  $('img', '#image').attr('src', 'images/medium/2.png'); // Change the src
});
```